# MATLAB SVMStruct (obtained from svmtrain) save in a file and read it later

Tags: matlab, svm

Is there a way by which I could write an SVMStruct (obtained using Matlab's `svmtrain`) to a file and then read it later when I need it. I want to do this because I'm unable to use `SVMclassify` after training the data, it gives out of memory error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `save` to save:

```
svmstruct=svmtrain(........
save('file2save.mat','svmstruct');
```

and `load` to reload it later:

```
load('file2save.mat','svmstruct');
svmclassify(svmstruct,.........
```